# postgres :: FATAL: could not access file "pglogical": No such file or directory

Tags: replication, postgresql-9.4

We installed pglogical from source code, we are running PostgreSQL 9.4

```
 make USE_PGXS=1 clean all
 make USE_PGXS=1 install
```

Installation was successful after updating the parameters, we tried restarting PostgreSQL and it responded with the above fatal error:

```
$ echo "include 'pglogical.conf'" >> $PGDATA/postgresql.conf
$ echo "wal_level = 'logical'" >> $PGDATA/pglogical.conf
$ echo "max_worker_processes = 10" >> $PGDATA/pglogical.conf
$ echo "max_replication_slots = 10" >> $PGDATA/pglogical.conf
$ echo "max_wal_senders = 10" >> $PGDATA/pglogical.conf
$ echo "shared_preload_libraries = 'pglogical'" >> $PGDATA/pglogical.conf
```

Basically I am trying to setup replication between 9.4 and 10, I was able to create the pglogical extension on 10.

Answer (score -1):

I just experienced the same issue on a development server where few people have been trying too many things..

For the next person, if you just want your DB to start, you can remove pglogical:

- Edit the file `data/postgresql.auto.conf`
- Remove `pglogical` from the `shared_preload_libraries` list.

Not sure how to help the exact scenario of the question though.